# Authentication between Google calendar and local server

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I am the server administrator of the internal system.

I would like to link Google Calendar with an application on the internal server.

When creating an OAuth 2.0 client ID, putting the URL of the local address in the redirect URI causes an error.

Since it can not be helped, I considered the server as a server with a virtual domain name (example: myhouse.com) and assigned it as a local address.
It was added to the "hosts" file on the target server.
(example: 192.168.1.111 myhouse.com)

This time, no error occurred when registering the Redirect URI.
However, when I attempted to authenticate on that application using that redirect URI, Google's authentication dialog came up and I could not authenticate. Google authentication has asked for authentication with an account called "myhouse.com".

In the first place, is it possible to collaborate with Google Calendar only on published servers?

Is it necessary to make a connection permission (release to Google server 
address and port) to the firewall of the in-house server?

It may be a basic question, but please give me advice.

Comment: what happens if you remove myhouse.com and just 192.168.1.111? Google APIs work on local servers as well (with internet connection using local web servers). The one I use is localhost:8080 (or some other ports).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, sorry for the late reply. When I attempted Google's OAuth 2 authentication with a local IP address, I got an error saying I need to use a domain name, not an IP address.